# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException palindromic primes

Tags: java, exception

I've been working on this code for class that needs to find the users desired number of palindromic prime numbers. Everything works fine when I have the while(primeCounter < desiredNumPrimes) except that it outputs one less than the desired number of prime numbers. I attempt to correct this by having the while statement be "<=" instead, but then I get an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception. As you can see, I even check to make sure that the index of the array is not less that the index I am attempting to use in the if statement

Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalPrimes
{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int primeCounter=1, numberToCheck=2; //start checking at 2 because primes >1

        System.out.println("Please enter the desired number of palindromic primes");

        int desiredNumPrimes = scan.nextInt();

        int[] palPrimes = new int[desiredNumPrimes-1];
        System.out.print(palPrimes.length);

        //find palindromic primes
        while(primeCounter<desiredNumPrimes){
            if(isPrime(numberToCheck)==true && isPalindrome(numberToCheck)==true){

                    palPrimes[primeCounter-1]= numberToCheck;

                numberToCheck++;
                primeCounter++;
            }
            else{
                numberToCheck++;
            }

        }

        //display palindromic primes
        if(primeCounter==desiredNumPrimes){
            for(int i = 0; i<palPrimes.length; i++){
                if(i%10==0){
                    System.out.println();
                }

                System.out.print(palPrimes[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    //Check if number is a prime    
        public static boolean isPrime(int num){
        if(num == 2){
            return true;
        }

        for( int divisor = 2; divisor <= num/2; divisor++){
            if (num % divisor ==0){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }

    //reverse number to begin testing if palindrome
    public static int reverse(int num){
        int testNum = 0;

        while(num !=0){
            int lastDigit = num%10;
            testNum = testNum*10+lastDigit;
            num = num/10;
        }

        return testNum;
    }

    //Check if number is a palindrome
    public static boolean isPalindrome( int num){

        return num == reverse(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. My logic in choosing to start the prime counter at 1 because I was starting my number to check at 2 (which is a prime number) I think was what was keeping me from seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

The issues are with initializations. The below 3 changes will resolve the issue. You are getting arrayindexoutofbounds since you are trying to change only the initialization but not the assignment

```
    int primeCounter with 0
    int[] palPrimes = new int[desiredNumPrimes];
    palPrimes[primeCounter]= numberToCheck;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the prime counter at 0 as you haven't found any primes yet.

```
int primeCounter=0, numberToCheck=2;
```

You're making the size of palPrimes 1 less than the desired number of primes, so it will never be able to contain the desired number of primes. Instead, make it

```
int[] palPrimes = new int[desiredNumPrimes];
```

Then, you check for palPrimes[primeCounter-1] = numberToCheck;
Seeing as we started the counter at 0, this should be changed to:

```
palPrimes[primeCounter] = numberToCheck;
```

And the program should work.